# Java script highlight text using text index

Tags: javascript

I am developing epub reader and i want to highlight selected text and save it during the next opening of this HTML i tried more than one method but all of them do not use index of text
for example

```
function load(){
 window.document.designMode = "On";
 window.document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, 'yellow');
  }
```

Pls need help
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438524/save-highlighted-text-position-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: This answer show how to return index but                           how can we do highlight using index of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/). It's library that handles cross-browser selection highlighting.

With the [Highlighter Module](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html) you can highlight the selected text.

However since HTML is stateless you won't be able to save it. You will have to serialize it with `highlighter.serialize()` and save the serialized string to a database or to a cookie.

It could look like this:

```
<script>
    // the highlighter object
    var highlighter;

    // function for the highlight button
    function highlightSelectedText() {
        highlighter.highlightSelection("highlight");
    }

    // function for the unhighlight button
    function removeHighlightFromSelectedText() {
        highlighter.unhighlightSelection();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        rangy.init();

        highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter();

        highlighter.addClassApplier(rangy.createCssClassApplier("highlight", {
            ignoreWhiteSpace: true,
            tagNames: ["span", "a"]
        }));

        // load the selection
        var selectionSerialized = loadSelection();
        if (selectionSerialized) {
            highlighter.deserialize(selectionSerialized);
        }
    };

    window.onunload = saveSelection;

    function saveSelection() {
        var selectionSerialized = highlighter.serialize()

        // save "selectionSerialized" to a cookie or use 
        // a webservice to send it to the server and save it there.
    }

    function loadSelection(){
        // here you must fetch the serialized string from the cookie or
        // from your webservice and return it.
    }

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="highlightSelectedText()" 
  value="Highlight selection">
<input type="button" onclick="removeHighlightFromSelectedText()" 
  value="Remove highlights from selection">
<div> bla bla bla .... </div>
```

Since I don't know how you want to store the serialization string, I skipped the saving and loading parts.

Comment: I tried the demo of this library but this is the first time to me to use java script i want to know the way of how to import the library in my java script code I am very sorry for this.