# How to keep range selected when using input in js

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an contenteditable div and i want to change the font size of selected range by typing font size in an input. But when i click on input after selecting a range it deselects.

The font size of selected range should change every time I change the value in input and the range should remain selected at that time.

```js
function changeFontSize() {
  let fontSize = `${document.getElementById('size').value}px`
  let input = document.getElementById('size')
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  console.log(fontSize)
  if (selection.rangeCount) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var content = range.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.fontSize = fontSize;

    // Recursively process child nodes
    for (var i = 0; i < content.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var node = content.childNodes[i];
      if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // For text nodes, wrap the text in a new span
        var childSpan = span.cloneNode(false);
        childSpan.appendChild(node.cloneNode(false));
        content.replaceChild(childSpan, node);
      } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        // For element nodes, recurse into the children
        changeFontSizeHelper(node, fontSize);
      }
    }

    range.insertNode(content);
  }

  function changeFontSizeHelper(node, fontSize) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var child = node.childNodes[i];
      if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.fontSize = fontSize;
        span.appendChild(child.cloneNode(false));
        node.replaceChild(span, child);
      } else if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        changeFontSizeHelper(child, fontSize);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <input type="number" id="size" class="btn btn-primary my-2 mx-1 options" onchange="changeFontSize()" style="width: 80px;" />
</li>
```

Comment: Can you add some more context to the question? I'm a little confused what you're trying to do, and what you've already tried. Perhaps a sample of the relevant html, along with more information on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @SamSabin I have updated the code and added a longer one and HTML also..

Comment: I feel like I'm still missing a lot of context when it comes to what range is representing and where the value is coming from. If you console.log() the value of selection.rangeCount before entering the if statement, is the value you're receiving expected, or is the selection deselected immediately upon clicking the input button?

Comment: Sure, that would be great

Comment: Mr. @SamSabin Here is the Codepen link:

https://codepen.io/Satyam-the-lessful/pen/bGZgxNz

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem. I'm sorry, you explained it well at the start. I was just a bit confused. I would look at these two Stack Overflow questions that explain how to save the user selection before it is deselected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786401/maintain-text-selection-when-using-div-as-a-button

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858725/how-to-maintain-selection-after-click-in-html

This jsfiddle from one of them is especially relevant: https://jsfiddle.net/uUqwZ/1/

Comment: Here is another Stack Overflow question that is also using a Range object similar to what you have done to store the data. I imagine if you combine this(which is similar to what you are already doing) with the preservation of the code using one of the examples sent before, perhaps that will help you find a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607578/how-can-i-persist-a-highlighted-selection-using-javascript

You could also save the user input upon change, and then reapply selection using Javascript, with the same serialization suggested in the linked StackOverflow solution.

Comment: The author of the StackOverflow solution has also created his own library to manage the serialization/selection process. Might be a good thing to look and see if that fits your use case: https://github.com/timdown/rangy

Seems the author has answered multiple Stack Overflow questions about this exact topic.

Comment: I made a snippet. It does not represent the problem. Please change it to be  a [mcve]

Comment: Mr. @mplungjan You can see the full code here.

https://codepen.io/Satyam-the-lessful/pen/bGZgxNz

Comment: I know, but I do not want to